# lxappearance not working on Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm 12

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, icons

So I recently installed the new Raspberry Pi OS, Bookworm 12 (the title says it all) and I want it to look nice, so I decided to install papirus.

I installed the apt repository and the `papirus-folders` command, and checked `lxappearance`. As expected, I saw 'Papirus-Dark' in there. I selected it, clicked apply, and nothing happened. Reboot, and still nothing. I launched `lxappearance`again and it showed me that PiXFlat (he default) was still selected. Selected Papirus-Dark again, quit, opened `lxappearance` again and still PiXFlat was selected.

I Have done that about 10 times and the same happened, and I've googled for about half an hour. What do I do? Any help appreciated.